# Why was Josh Primo waived?

Tags: basketball, nba, transaction

[Josh Primo was waived by the San Antonio Spurs on 2022-10-28](https://www.nba.com/news/josh-primo-waived-spurs).

He was a high draft pick and by many accounts and up and coming player. Why waive him? I'm sure the the Spurs could have got draft picks or some compensation for a player with his potential.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it was [at his request](https://www.poundingtherock.com/2022/10/28/23429500/josh-primo-cites-mental-health-as-his-reason-for-leaving-the-spurs), or at least a mutual decision, with him citing the need to take care of his mental health as the reason.

Reports indicate that he apparently was waived after [exposing himself to several women](https://www.espn.com/nba/story/_/id/34904011/sources-joshua-primo-allegedly-exposed-women).

Comment: And there goes my sympathy for him. It did seem surprising that the league, the team and the NBPA didn't work something out if his mental health was the only issue, particularly after the Ben Simmons stuff.